# Arch Linux not picking up static DHCP lease from DD-WRT

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dhcp, dd-wrt

I have a Arch Linux system on my home network and its MAC address is setup in my Linksys running DD-WRT to receive a static lease. However, this system is not getting the static lease from the DD-WRT, but rather a random ip from the dynamic pool. I tried various things, like forcing a lease renewal, but to no avail. How should I go about troubleshooting this problem? Running Arch Linux 201404 with a wired connection. I am new to Arch, but been a long time Debian user, so the Arch `ip` toolset is not too familiar to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this exact thing this morning.

First, double check that the lease isn't allocated. Go to the Status page and then the LAN page on DD-WRT. Check the lease in the list of DHCP clients. If it's allocated, click the trash can.

I also have my lease set to 5 minutes. If I left it for a whole day, which is the default, I found that if the signal got disrupted, my computer would disconnect and when it reconnected, the lease would still be allocated and so it would take an address from the pool. That messed with my port forwards. Setting it to 5 minutes prevented that.

Then, following from [this part of the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Manual_setup), you need to find the name and MAC of your wireless NIC:

`$ iw dev`

Make sure you're using that MAC in your static lease on DD-WRT as the wired one will be different (I've made that mistake before).

Checking the status of your link is done via:

`$ iw dev wlan0 link`

It will either say `Not Connected` or give you information about your access point. At this point you don't want to be connected so if you are, issue:

`# iw dev wlan0 disconnect`

The wiki says that interface activation is not usually necessary, though for me it was. You can check the status with:

`# ip link show wlan0`

Don't pay attention to the `state` but look for the word `UP` inside the `<...>`.

If it's not up, use:

`# ip link set wlan0 up`

I'm going to assume that you know your SSID. In which case to connect to the access point, you can use:

`# iw dev wlan0 connect your_essid`

if it's open or:

`# wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

if you're using WPA, after providing the appropriate details in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Now recheck that you're associated with the access point by reissuing:

`$ iw dev wlan0 link`

Finally, you'll want to obtain an IP address by issuing:

`# dhcpcd wlan0`

DD-WRT should then match the MAC of your wireless NIC and issue the static lease address to you.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that the lease was already allocated from the previous instance of the machine before I rebuilt it with Arch.